# Firebase 9 modular -how to start

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I try to start playing with Firebase 9. I use VSCode and export using npm (in vscode)

```
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0-beta.5/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
   
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0-beta.5/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
  
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0-beta.5/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0-beta.5/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0-beta.5/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- init -->
    <script defer src="firebase/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    
    <script type="module">
    import {
        getAuth,
        onAuthStateChanged
    } from "firebase/auth";

    const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
        console.log(user)
    });
      </script>
```

Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "firebase/auth". Relative references must start with either "/", "./",
> or "../".

Comment: What I understood on this code should work modular and v8 as well.

Comment: It will but with NPM/Yarn or any module bundler only (like a Vue/React app). Please refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/issues/192#issuecomment-872204103). It does say 'compat' in the script URL itself so I assume that pkg has v8 syntax only

Comment: Thank you. I installed using npm on vscode but still problem with import. The npm created folder "node_modules" where I believe is all what I need. I would prefer to use vanilla js than react or vue. Regards

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Im having the same issue

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. I can't find a working example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and was able to resolve it by closely watching David's [video around the 5:40 timestamp](https://youtu.be/rQvOAnNvcNQ?t=343).

Here is the basic boilerplate that works when serving locally:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-auth.js';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  // (insert your Firebase configuration here)
  });

  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('Logged in as ${user.email}' );
    } else {
      console.log('No user');
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting started with Firebase Auth</title>
    <script type="module" src="/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did you get this way to make it? i'm asking because in the official docs does not show anything like your code

Comment: here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using now (thank you Peter)

```
 // initialize 
import {
    initializeApp
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "1:xx:web:xx",
    measurementId: "G-xx"
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Add Firebase products that you want to use
import {
    getAuth,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-auth.js';

import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,
    getDocs,
    getDoc,
    doc,
    setDoc
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-firestore.js';
import {
    getStorage,
    ref,
    uploadBytesResumable,
    getDownloadURL,
    listAll,
    deleteObject
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-storage.js";
//============================================
//============================================
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
let UID;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            UID = user.uid;
            //Your code...
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Peter Friese](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69010744/21474770)'s answer is perfect

BUT PLS DO THIS INSTEAD:

```
console.log('Logged in as ( ' + user.email +' )');
```

NOT LIKE THIS:

```
console.log('Logged in as ${user.email}' );
```