# Why getting Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, module, firebase-authentication

I have shifted my code from v8 to v9 version with modular code,but I am getting this error inspite of having installed the rollup package.
My JS Code:

```
<script type="module">
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
      import firebase from 'firebase';
      import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
      import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
      import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
      //app config
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
      const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    </script>
```

The error I am getting:  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

I have spent considerable time but unable to find the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase 9 modular -how to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209854/firebase-9-modular-how-to-start)

Comment: @Dharmaraj
  It couldnt resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar error. I solved this error like this.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-app.js'
import { getAuth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-auth.js'
```

I think you can use those URL.

I am not sure this is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand a big part of firebase 9 is that you no longer need to import the entire firebase, and can now just import whatever modules you need.

You therefore do not need to

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

Try not importing "firebase" and see what happens

Comment: still getting the same error after removing that line