# Importing Firebase not working even though everything is installed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, npm

I created simple website in order to learn Firebase **9**, but it doesn't work properly when I try to import any of firebase files.

I've looked for tutorials how to config firebase, but they either don't solve my problem or are about the older (thus completely different) version of firebase.

In index.js I added window.alert("OK"); in order to know whether my code works. It does, but only when I comment all the import firebase lines (or at least the one in index.js).

I think I have installed npm and firebase correctly, but I'll add the screenshot of my folder (maybe something should be in different direction (?)).

My folder:

[image: my folder]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>User portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="card" id="login">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <div class="header">Hi!</div>
        <p>Sign up or Sign in!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <div>
            E-mail:
          <br>
          <input class="input" id="userEmail" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Aa">
          <p>
              Password:
            <br>
            <input class="input" id="userPass" type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Aa">
          </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          <button class="button" onclick="logIn()">
            Log in!
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="card" id="logged-in">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <div class="header">Hi!</div>
        <p>Welcome to your account!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <p>
          <button class="button" onclick="logOut()">
            Log out!
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="load.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

function logIn() {

  window.alert("OK");
  var uE = document.getElementById("userEmail").value;
  var uP = document.getElementById("userPass").value;

}

function logOut() {
  document.getElementById("login").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("logged-in").style.display = "none";
}
```

load.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCOyINuV-Ppeq8ShseJiTOVGS7_ZU9SiTg",
  authDomain: "login-9e245.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "login-9e245",
  storageBucket: "login-9e245.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "926078358623",
  appId: "1:926078358623:web:2a0fa27e6f9066cec037ea",
  measurementId: "G-DKKZ0632PT"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Please help me with it, because I want to learn something.

Comment: Also where are you loading the actual Firebase SDK?

Comment: I think your using NPM to import firebase but your not using a bundler are you? if that's not the case import firebase using the script tag like following: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup

Comment: And how should I configure it to use a bundler? What should I do? Don't like the idea of "alternative ways" do I'd like it to configure it the best way (I assume with the use of the bundler).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having the same issue as the following thread:
Your using npm without a bundler. Try importing firebase like in the thread below.

[Firebase 9 modular -how to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209854/firebase-9-modular-how-to-start)

Here is the basic boilerplate that works when serving locally:

index.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-auth.js';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  // (insert your Firebase configuration here)
  });

  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('Logged in as ${user.email}' );
    } else {
      console.log('No user');
    }
  });
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Getting started with Firebase Auth</title>
    <script type="module" src="/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I kind of got your code working. I changed both your scripts to modules and instead of exporting the logout and login functions I used event listeners on the buttons

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>User portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="card" id="login">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <div class="header">Hi!</div>
        <p>Sign up or Sign in!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <div>
          E-mail:
          <br />
          <input class="input" id="userEmail" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Aa" />
          <p>
            Password:
            <br />
            <input class="input" id="userPass" type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Aa" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          <button class="button login">Log in!</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="logged-in">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <div class="header">Hi!</div>
        <p>Welcome to your account!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <p>
          <button class="button logout">Log out!</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="load.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

load.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAnalytics } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-analytics.js';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCOyINuV-Ppeq8ShseJiTOVGS7_ZU9SiTg',
  authDomain: 'login-9e245.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'login-9e245',
  storageBucket: 'login-9e245.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '926078358623',
  appId: '1:926078358623:web:2a0fa27e6f9066cec037ea',
  measurementId: 'G-DKKZ0632PT',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export default app;
```

index.js:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-auth.js';
import app from './load.js';

document.querySelector('.login').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.alert('OK');
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('Logged in as ${user.email}');
    } else {
      console.log('No user');
    }
  });
  var uE = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
  var uP = document.getElementById('userPass').value;
});

document.querySelector('.logout').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('logged-in').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Is there something I may need to change when publishing it? Like using hosting on Firebase. I'm asking, because you said it's for serving locally.

Comment: Did you try above? this is how you connect your frontend with firebase to be able to use the firebase features. Try the code about with your initializeApp config, it should work. As you can see your importing from gstatic instead of your node-modules

Comment: It doesnt matter if you serve locally or use a service like netlify or something like that to host your frontend, this implementation is the same if you don't use a bundler. Other cases are if you use React or Vue they come with a bundler like Webpack or parcel so you can use node modules out of the box.

Comment: It does not work ;(

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: well, I don't get any error, because I use vanilla JS and just open index.html in the browser, so due to my own "debugging techniques" I can see that when firebase import is not commented then everything in JS file works fine (except obviously for thew firebase part which is then commented).

By that I mean that function logIn() has window.alert("OK"); and it displays when I click button AND import {initializeApp} from 'firebase_link' is commented. When it's not then the logIn() function does not display the alert.

Comment: I recommend you just use a bundler. The easiest thing to use for you for plain JS is Vite. Try that let me know if you have any luck.
https://vitejs.dev/

Comment: ERROR in external "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js"
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Comment: Now I use webpack and this occurs

Comment: When you use webpack you can use node-modules. don't use the static. try webpack or vite like in my other answer.

Comment: GET file:///.../index.js net::ERR_FAILED
Access to script at 'file:///.../index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: Does your EDIT code use webpack or any other kind of package bundler?

Comment: Btw I think I need to give up. Can you just write for me the simplest page (using hopefully only npm and firebase) that just gets logged in user? I don't know how to learn the firebase if the things are going this way (a lot of errors even before writing more complex code eh).

Comment: If I make one using Vite below can you use it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying a frontend tooling library like Vite.

```
# npm 6.x
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app --template vanilla

# npm 7+, extra double-dash is needed:
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vanilla

# yarn
yarn create vite my-vue-app --template vanilla

# pnpm
pnpm create vite my-vue-app -- --template vanilla
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an account in your config using the following code.
Dont forget to install vite using:

```
npm create vite@latest firebasedemo --template vanilla
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>User portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="card" id="login">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <div class="header">Hi!</div>
        <p>Sign up or Sign in!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <div>
          E-mail:
          <br />
          <input class="input" id="userEmail" type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Aa" />
          <p>
            Password:
            <br />
            <input class="input" id="userPass" type="password" name="pass" value="" placeholder="Aa" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          <button class="button login">Log in!</button>
          <button class="button create">Create Account</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="logged-in">
      <div class="paragraph">
        <div class="header">Hi!</div>
        <p>Welcome to your account!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <p>
          <button class="button logout">Log out!</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import './style.css';
import app from './firebaseConfig';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});

document.querySelector('.create').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var uE = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
  var uP = document.getElementById('userPass').value;

  const auth = getAuth();
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, uE, uP)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log('logged in');
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
    });
});

document.querySelector('.login').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var uE = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
  var uP = document.getElementById('userPass').value;
});

document.querySelector('.logout').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('logged-in').style.display = 'none';
  console.log('test2');
});
```

firebaseConfig.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCOyINuV-Ppeq8ShseJiTOVGS7_ZU9SiTg',
  authDomain: 'login-9e245.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'login-9e245',
  storageBucket: 'login-9e245.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '926078358623',
  appId: '1:926078358623:web:2a0fa27e6f9066cec037ea',
  measurementId: 'G-DKKZ0632PT',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default app;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "firebasedemo",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11"
  }
}
```